# Julia Gtk CssProviderLeaf performance

Tags: julia, gtk3

why CssProviderLeaf lasts about 1600 milliseconds?

```
julia> using Gtk

julia> name ="FieldName"
"FieldName"

julia> @time Gtk.CssProviderLeaf(data="#$name {background:#C0C0C0;border-width:2px}")
  3.397363 seconds (118.32 k allocations: 5.960 MiB, 7.66% compilation time)
GtkCssProviderLeaf()

julia> @time Gtk.CssProviderLeaf(data="#name {background:#C0C0C0;border-width:2px}")
  3.968938 seconds (6 allocations: 96 bytes)
GtkCssProviderLeaf()
```

This occurs in Windows 10 both with version 1.8.1 and with version 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the function in https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl/blob/master/src/theme.jl:

```
function GtkCssProviderLeaf(; data = nothing, filename = nothing)
    source_count = (data !== nothing) + (filename !== nothing)
    @assert(source_count <= 1,
        "GtkCssProvider must have at most one data or filename argument")
    provider = GtkCssProviderLeaf(ccall((:gtk_css_provider_new, libgtk),   Ptr{GObject}, ()))
    if data !== nothing
        GError() do error_check
            ccall((:gtk_css_provider_load_from_data, libgtk), Bool,
            (Ptr{GObject}, Ptr{UInt8}, Clong, Ptr{Ptr{GError}}),
            provider, bytestring(data), -1, error_check)
        end
    elseif filename !== nothing
        GError() do error_check
            ccall((:gtk_css_provider_load_from_path, libgtk), Bool,
            (Ptr{GObject}, Ptr{UInt8}, Ptr{Ptr{GError}}),
            provider, bytestring(filename), error_check)
        end
    end
    return provider
end
```

it seems the delay is in the call to libgtk. You might want to see if you can minimize the times this has to be called in the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Bill

a Julia expert shows me that the answer has been very fast:

```
julia> @time Gtk.CssProviderLeaf(data="#name {background:#C0C0C0;border-width:2px}")
  0.000078 seconds (6 allocations: 96 bytes)
```

My be he is running on Linux system,the problem can be on the Windows operating system?